# Get id of selected row in a table -HTML

Tags: jquery, html

I have a table in my MVC application.I want to get the id of the selected row.I captured the click event of tr using jQuery.  The table sample  is shown below

```
<table id="resultTable">
 <tr id="first">
  <td>c1</td>      
  <td>c2</td>      
 </tr>
 <tr id="second">
  <td>c3</td>      
  <td>c4</td>      
  </tr>    
</table>
```

I am using following script to access row click event

```
 $(document).ready(function () {      
     $('#resultTable tr').click(function (event) {
          alert(this.); //trying to alert id of the clicked row          

     });
 });
```

But its not working.How can get selected row id .??Any ideas??

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {      
     $('#resultTable tr').click(function (event) {
          alert($(this).attr('id')); //trying to alert id of the clicked row          

     });
 });
```

Answer (score 6):

You were almost there. Just access it directly:

```
alert(this.id);
```