# How to display details about specific record on a same page in ASP.net MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have two divs on my view, the left one contains all of the products available. I want to display the details of the product selected on the same page in the right div. When I first load the page, the right div should contain the first record's details. After that, when I click on any of the links, it should change the details. I'm new to MVC and Entity Framework. I have tried to do it but have no idea. If I want to display the details in the next page after clicking on the hyperlink of the product, I can do that. Please try to solve my problem. Thanks!

Products.cshtml:

```
@model List<productList.Models.tbl_product>

<div class="product">
    <ul class="list">
        @foreach(var item in Model)
        {
            <li>
                <a href='@Url.Action("Product","Home",new {id = item.ProductId })'>
                     <span class="ProductName">@item.ProductName</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            </span></a>
</div>

<div class="productDetails">
    <ul class="listdetails">
        @foreach(var item in Model)
        {
            <li> 
                <span class="ProductName">@item.ProductName</span>
                <div class="ProductDesc">
                    @item.ProductDetails
                </div>
            </li>
        }
```

HomeController.cs:

```
public ActionResult Product()
{
    return View(dbentity.tbl_product.ToList());
}
```

Comment: use an ajax call for this.  build a partial view to display the details of the clicked item and refresh the partial on click of the first div.  see my answer here

Comment: Can You give the link of some example of this type of questions.....

Comment: basically u need two action methods, main view, partialview and code for ajax call. I updated with my answer :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20071301/how-to-open-window-in-the-same-view-in-mvc-4/20080267#20080267 didn't paste the link.  I apologize

Comment: Please clean up your code. I tried my best to edit it, but it has some extra html tags, and some are missing.

Answer (score 0):

Use RenderPartial for the first product load, after that use jQuery ajax to load other

Controller action for first product list load

```
public ActionResult Product()
{
  return View(dbentity.tbl_product.ToList());
}
```

***PartialView.cshtml***

```
@model Product

<label>Name:</label>@model.Name
```

***In Main View***

```
@model IList<Product>
<div class="product">
<ul class="list">
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
<li> <a href=@Url.Action("ProductDetail","Home",new {id=item.ProductId})'
<span class="ProductName"> @item.ProductName</span></a></li>    
}
</ul>
</div>

<div id="product-detail">
 @{Html.RenderPartial("PartialView", Model.FirstOrDefault());}
</div>
```

Also you need another action for loading each product

```
public ActionResult ProductDetail(int id)
{
var model=products.Find(id);
return ("PartialView",model);
}
```

***AJAX CALL***

```
$("div.product a").click(function(e){

  var url=this.href;
  $.get(url,{},function(data){
  $('#product-detail').html(data);
  });
  e.preventDefault();

});
```

Comment: I have tried to use partial view but a new page is opened which is partial view and details of records is displayed there. I want that on same page.

Comment: @user2802591, added `e.preventDefault()` in the above code which will prevent opening the result in new window.