# What is the solution of loading and calling multiple panels/partialviews in Mvc?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am having trouble with loading multiple partialviews in the same page and loading one view based on the data from the other view, here is the problem:
I have on the left a panel with collection and when a collection is selected the items will appear on the right top panel and here I can select an item that will have the details displayed on the bottom panel.

I have created a layout with a several tables and loading the collection from the left but when I click on an item this goes in the "new page" and does not keep the layout because it loads a partialview. How can I implement something like this in ASP.NET MVC?

Here is what I am using just to have an idea: 
in layout :

```
@Html.Action("Categories", "Home")
```

and in partial view :

```
@Html.ActionLink(@item3.Name, "Items", "Home", new { @item3.Id })
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: See my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20071301/how-to-open-window-in-the-same-view-in-mvc-4/20080267#20080267

Answer (score 0):

Are you loading partial view through Ajax if yes then on click of action link use event.preventDefault() and event.StopImmediatePropogation() to stop opening in the new page.

Answer (score 0):

Use @Html.RenderPartial("ControllerName").
Hope this help you