# Is using the default add/edit/delete <Table> bad? And how would I refresh this using AJAX?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using the basic tables that come with the EF Index/details/add/edit/delete. Now I'm also using the default tables that it gives you and I'm just working with this. So my question is, is this bad? I've seen alot of things online to do with web matrix's and various other Jquery for handling this.

I'm not to keen on changing it as it works with the pagination etc that the MVC 5 guides help you do.

And on that note, how would I refresh these tables automatically once every 5 mins for example? I know how to refresh the page, but not how to call the method again just for table (If that's even possible). Ta.

Comment: my thought is if it is working for you, don't try to fix it :).  for the ajax call see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20071301/how-to-open-window-in-the-same-view-in-mvc-4/20080267#20080267 (put your table in a partial that you can reload as needed)

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at JTable? Its great, however if your existing thing is working gud then no need to change. JTable has lots of features where in you can specify List Action method that returns the records that can be binded to it. You can use javascript 'setInterval' method to invoke the controller method that will return the records on periodic interval and rebind the jtable, that way you would not be required to reload the entire page again.

```
 $('#DivID').jtable({
            paging: true,
            sorting: true,
            pageSize: 10,
            pageList: 'normal',
            pageSizeChangeArea: true,
            defaultSorting: 'FieldName ASC',
            type: 'POST',
            title: 'Actual P&L',
            actions: {
                listAction: 'GetResults'
            },
            fields: {
             }
```