# passing value from javascript to ajax in mvc4

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

i need to select a value from a grid and pass it to ajax. I'm getting the error as "Id undefined". can anyone suggest me a solution for this issue. Records most be deleted which a presented in grid. on clicking the button selected value must got to ajax function for deletion process. value s moved to ajax but getting error that the policyid is undefined Thanks in advance.

Code of grid column:

```
@{
    var grid = new WebGrid(Model.Policy, rowsPerPage: 20, selectionFieldName: "selectedRow", ajaxUpdateContainerId: "gridcal");
              grid.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.NextPrevious);}
    @grid.GetHtml(
    tableStyle: "webgrid-table",
    headerStyle: "webgrid-header",
    footerStyle: "webgrid-footer",
    alternatingRowStyle: "webgrid-alternating-row",
    selectedRowStyle: "webgrid-selected-row",
    rowStyle: "webgrid-row-style",
    columns:
        grid.Columns(
        grid.Column("PolicyName","Policy Name",style: "colWidth"),
        grid.Column("PolicyValue","Policy Value",style: "colWidth"),
       // grid.Column ("Delete",format:@<text><a href="@Url.Action("DeletePolicy","Roles",new{PolicyId=item.PolicyId.ToString()})"><img src="~/Images/img-delete-blk-icon.png" width="9" height="9" alt="Delete"/></a> </text>)
        ****grid.Column(format: @<text><input type="image"  onclick="AJAXCall_Fun_DeletePolicy()" src="~/Images/img-delete-blk-icon.png" name="image" width="9" height="9" /></text>)****


            ))

             @if (grid.HasSelection)
                    {

                        <b>Policy Name</b>@AppliedPolicies.PolicyName<br />
                        <b>Policy Value</b>@AppliedPolicies.PolicyValue<br />

                    }
```

Ajax :

```
 function AJAXCall_Fun_DeletePolicy() {

    if ($.xhrPool.length > 0) {
        $.each($.xhrPool, function (idx, jqXHR) {
            if (jqXHR) {
                this.abort();
            }
        });
        $.xhrPool = [];
    }


  var PolicyId = PolicyId();
    if (PolicyId.length > 0) {
        $.ajax({

            type: "GET",
            url: "/Roles/DeletePolicy",
            data: { 'PolicyId': JSON.stringify(PolicyId) },
            async: true,
            cache: false,
            datatype: "json",
```

Controller code:

```
    public JsonResult DeletePolicy(string PolicyId)
    {
        bool status = false;
        using (clsBLLGroups objclsBLLGroups = new clsBLLGroups())
        {
            status = objclsBLLGroups.DeletePolicy(UserCookieWrapper.UserAccessToken, PolicyId.ToString());


        }
        return Json(status, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: What does PolicyId() do, you did not show the code here

Comment: the selected PolicyId() should be deleted

Comment: What does PolicyId(); do in javascript ? You haven't defined

Comment: You cannot access controller using javascript directly. as a result 'var PolicyId' is not getting any data.Try to do this in a different way

Answer (score 0):

a web grid renders as a table so use [Get id of selected row in a table -HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142422/get-id-of-selected-row-in-a-table-html) to get the id of clicked row and you can pass that through your ajax call to the controller.
  You mentioned PolicyId is controller code.  If you want to include a value from your model in your ajax call you just need to use @

```
var PolicyId = '@(Model.PolicyId)';
```

you can use that for your url as well.  We use

```
url: '@Url.Action("DeletePolicy", "Roles")',
```

for our url.  Hope this helps