# How to select the Selected Row ID from radiobutton field in MVC 4 WebGrid?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, radio-button, webgrid

Please help me to select the Selected Row ID from radiobutton field in MVC 4 WebGrid? I am not submitting the form, but pointing to HTTpGet action Method of the same view using a button.

Here is the View:

```
var grid = new WebGrid(ViewBag.inCompletePipelines, canPage: true, rowsPerPage: 10,
                            selectionFieldName: "selectedRow", ajaxUpdateContainerId: "inCompletePipelines");
                            grid.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.NextPrevious); 
                            <div id="gridinCompletePipelines" class="gridwidthLong">
                                    @grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "webGrid",
                                    headerStyle: "header",
                                    alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
                                    selectedRowStyle: "select",




                                    columns: grid.Columns(                                                                            
                                    grid.Column("Name", " Pipeline Name"),
                                    grid.Column("Length", " Length"),
                                    grid.Column("ModifiedDate", "Modified Date"),
                                    grid.Column("ModifiedBy", "Modified By"),
                                    grid.Column(
            header: "Select", 
            format: @<text>@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Id, (int)item.Id)</text>
        )

                                    )) 



@Html.ActionLink("New Pipeline", "pipelines_saved", "PipeLine", new { Id= grid.SelectedRowID ???????? }, new {@class = "roundedButton" })
```

Comment: the web grid just renders as a table.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142422/get-id-of-selected-row-in-a-table-html