# How to get selected row from a table in html using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a html table and a button below it, I want to get the data from the selected row whenever that button is clicked. How shall I go about it?

Comment: What do you mean by "*get the data*"?

Comment: you should post your code(markup/javasciprt)

Comment: What does it mean to “select” a row? Do you have checkboxes?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142422/get-id-of-selected-row-in-a-table-html

Comment: @AndersonGreen—that link isn't helpful.

Comment: You might want to consider using a library like Datatables or jqGrid.

Comment: document.activeElement is the last element activated

Comment: post the code along with our html @user3221714

Comment: @PM 77-1 - from data I meant the visible/invisible data which is being displayed in a row in the table.

Comment: @minitech - In core java swings whenever you click on a row in a table, it gets selected but in HTML that is not the case (I think), you actually have to change the style of the row in order to make it look selected. So by "Selecting a row" I meant to distinguish between a specific row from rest of the rows in the table.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you mean, you want a user to be able to select a row out of a table by clicking on it.  Then when they click the button, you can capture the selected row's data in each cell.

I'll use JQuery in the explanation.

You will want to create an event handler for a click event on a `<tr>`.  When that `<tr>` is clicked, you can apply a CSS class such as `.selected` to it.  Then when the user clicks the button, you have another event handler loop through the `.selected` class's children and return the values (which would be `<td>`'s).

```
$('tr').click(function() {
   $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});

$('#submit').click(function() {    
    $('.selected').children().each(function() {
        alert($(this).html());
    });
});
```

Here is a [working example on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b39xcuac/) using JQuery.

Comment: Thanks Eclecticist, I already figured out what you have suggested in the post above and did exactly what you have written in the code.