# MVC get details from partial view to show in textboxes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have 3 views (1 Index, 2 Contacts(partialview), 3 Details(partialview))

I have a database with 2 tables tied by ContactId that i can use to get the Details from the database to show. I used ADO to make a model of the database. The 2 tables (classes) are named Contact and ContactTelefon.

Instead of button I tried using `@html.ActionLink` (as u can see in Contact View) to get the Id from the row, but that takes me to a new page, and it doesn't even show details.

My question is: **How could i get the details to show in textboxes so i can edit the data.**

All actions must be in same view as far as the user is concerned.

**Controller:**

```
ContactsDbEntities db = new ContactsDbEntities();

[HttpGet] //Index
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
//Contacts
public ViewResult Contacts()
{
    var contactsList = db.Contacts.ToList();
    return View(contactsList);
}

//Details
public ActionResult Details(int? id)
{
    ContactTelefon contactTel = db.ContactTelefons.Find(id);
    return View(contactTel);
}
```

**Index view**

```
@using Demo.Models
@model Contact

@section scripts
{
    <link href="~/Content/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(function () {
            $(document).on('click', '#Details', function () {
                $.get('@Url.Action("Details","Home")', function (data) {
                    $('#divDetails').replaceWith(data);
                });
            });
    </script>
}

<table id="mainTable" class="table table-bordered table-striped">

    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ContactId)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Nume)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Prenume)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Adresa)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Mentiuni)
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>

        </th>
        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            <th>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Nume, null, new { id = "txtSearchNume", @class = "form-control" })
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Prenume, null, new { id = "txtSearchPrenume", @class = "form-control" })
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Adresa, null, new { id = "txtSearchAdresa", @class = "form-control" })
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Mentiuni, null, new { id = "txtSearchMentiuni", @class = "form-control" })

            </th>
            <th>
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-success"
                       onclick=" location.href='@Url.Action("Index", "Home")' " />
            </th>
            <th>
                <input type="submit" name="submitSearch" value="Search" class="btn btn-info"
                       onclick=" location.href='@Url.Action("Create", "Home")' " />
            </th>
            <tr>
                @{Html.RenderAction("Contacts", "Home");}
            </tr>
            <tr><div id="divDetails"></div></tr>
        }

    </table>
```

**Contacts View**

```
@using Demo.Models
@model IEnumerable<Contact>

<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ContactId)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nume)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Prenume)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Adresa)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Mentiuni)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.ContactId },
                    new { @class = "btn btn-danger", onclick = "return confirm('Delete this record?');" })
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="Details" type="button" name="Details"
                       value="Details" class="btn btn-info" />
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("DetailsLink","Details",new{id = item.ContactId})
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

**Details View**

```
@using Demo.Models
@model ContactTelefon     

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <div claass="form-group">
        @* must get the id from Contacts *@

        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ContactId)

        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ContactTelefonId)

        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NumarTelefon)

        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TipNumarTelefon)
    </div>
    <br />
    <div claass="form-group">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ContactId)

        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ContactTelefonId)

        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.NumarTelefon)

        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.TipNumarTelefon)
    </div>
    <div claass="form-group">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ContactId)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ContactTelefonId)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NumarTelefon)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TipNumarTelefon)
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If contacts and details are partial views then you should not have an actionMethod calling their models. Rather create a viewmodel with the index actionmethod retrieving the models , then pass the models from the viewmodel into the partial view. This does not answer the question but should be a step in the right direction.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142422/get-id-of-selected-row-in-a-table-html this is a link for getting the id of the selected row.  pass that in your ajax call and build your model accordingly

Comment: @Matt Bodidly that is something, but this would be sort of hardcoding it. I need the ContactId from the database. I tried using ActionLink, like Delete Action is using it, but i get no result and it's not even showing up on the same page like i want.

Comment: So you want the details to appear inline on your list page when you click on the link?

Comment: I need the details to appear both in the details partial view that can be a simple table line, and also in the textboxes so the user can edit them.

Comment: I understand now. I'll try to post a good answer when I'm done with work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as if you're starting MVC coming from ASP.NET WebForms. The thing about MVC is that it doesn't do any magic like WebForms so you have to have a good understanding of what happens behind the scenes to be able to make a smooth transition. Also, from the looks of it your database model uses Entity Framework.

First off the way you're handling the `Details` button is all wrong. What you should be doing is this:

**HTML**

```
<input type="button" name="Details" value="Details" class="btn btn-info js-details" 
    data-id="@item.ContactId" />
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).on('click', '.js-details', function (event) {

    // get the element that triggered the event
    var $element = $(event.currentTarget);
    var id = $element.data('id');

    // you might have to type in the literal URL if you have a custom route 
    // here
    $.get('@Url.Action("Details","Home")'+ '?id=' + id, function (data) {
        $('#divDetails').html(data);
    });
});
```

Let me know if this works for you. There are other things that you can improve but this should be a pretty good start.

Comment: Every day i wonder why i keep trying with MVC without understanding major concepts, but it's something that keeps me going. Don't know exactly what. I would talk hours about it... Anyway your solution is what i needed to get me started. I will adapt it to some other needs aswell. Thanks!

Comment: If you have any questions about the various concepts in MVC i'd be more than happy to help. I've been doing it for a while and I know most of the ins & outs as well as best practices. I'm no Jon Skeet but I can help.

Comment: I wouldn't know where to start! Actually i'm having trouble getting a grip on the zillion methods of sening data from the controller to the view. Especially when dealing with a "strongly typed view". Where did u start with MVC? And what did u do to feel comfortable with it? Every day i feel like i know so manny concepts and every day i learn new hings, yet i feel like don't know anything, and it's probably 99% true.

Comment: I did PHP and ASP.NET WebForms before MVC and when I started, it was like nothing else. It took me years to get a good handle on it. The best advice I can give you is the same advice the friend who got me into MVC gave me: **there's no magic in MVC**. In truth, there is some "magic" in how it does things (like routing and controller/view resolution) but those are deep beneath the hood. For a novice like you it's great advice though because you have to understand that MVC doesn't do anything for you. If something doesn't work it's because you missed a piece.