# MVC Search in a non-IEnumerable Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a Search Method working for an IEnumerable model.

How to make it work with simple model? (or how is it called..)

**Controller:**

```
 [HttpPost] //FOR SEARCH (WORKING)
    public ActionResult Search(string searchNume)
    {
        List<Contact> contactsList;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchNume))
        {
            contactsList = db.Contacts.ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            contactsList = db.Contacts.Where(x => x.Nume.Contains(searchNume)).ToList();
        }
        return View(contactsList);
    }
```

**View:**

```
@using Demo.Model.Contact
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        <th>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Nume)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Prenume)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Adresa)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Mentiuni)
        </th>
        <th>
            <input type="submit" name="submitSearch" value="Search" class="btn btn-info"
                   onclick=" location.href='@Url.Action("Search", "Home")' " />
        </th>
```

**UPDATE1:** Changed Index ActionResult to Search

**UPDATE2:** Posted more of the index view

**Update3:** Reposting the code after changes

```
        ////Search GET
    //[ChildActionOnly]
    public PartialViewResult Search() // for displaying the initial view with all contacts
    {
        List<Contact> contactsList = db.Contacts.ToList();
        return PartialView("Contacts", contactsList);
    }

    ////Search POST
    [HttpPost]
    public PartialViewResult Search(string txtsearchNume)
    {
        List<Contact> contactsList;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtsearchNume))
        {
            contactsList = db.Contacts.ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            contactsList = db.Contacts.Where(x => x.Nume.Contains(txtsearchNume)).ToList();
        }
        return PartialView("Contacts", contactsList);
    }
```

**View:**

```
    @using Demo.Models
    @model Contact

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@section scripts
{
    <link href="~/Content/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>    
    <script>            

            //Search
            var url = '@Url.Action("Search", "Home")';
            var filter = $('#Nume');
            var results = $('#results');
            $('#search').click(function () {
                results.load(url, { txtsearchNume: filter.val() });
            });    

        });
    </script>
}    

        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {       
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Nume, null, new { id = "txtSearchNume", @class = "form-control" })

                <button type="button" id="search">Search by Nume</button>
           }

<div id="results">
    @Html.Action("Search")  
</div>
```

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. Is the view you have shown for the `Index()` method (in which case it does not work)? What is the `Search` method your refer to in the `onclick` event and since you don't pass any parameters to the method, what result are you expecting?

Comment: do you want to fill (reload) some kind of grid with Ajax (async) search call?

Comment: I'm searching though a table, and this method used to work when i was using Ienumerable model for that view. I needed to change the model to simple and now i also have to change the Controller Action, because it sais Model List not assignable to model type Demo.Models.
I'm expecting a list of matching items from the database table items. I will update question with the full index view so u can see better i guess.

Comment: If you want a standard submit, then make the method a GET (not a post) and include a form (`FormMethod.Get`) with a textbox (`name="searchNume"`) and submit button so that you pass the value of the textbox to the `Index()` method, otherwise use ajax to a method that returns a partial view with the result and update the DOM.

Comment: What are you trying to do here. Why do you have `onclick=" location.href='@Url.Action("Search", "Home")` in the submit button? If will pass nothing to the `Search()` method. And if you remove it you will post back a model of type `Contact` but the method expects parameter `string searchNume` Your query suggests you want to search by property `Nume` so whats the point of the other 3 textboxes?

Comment: onclick=" location.href='@Url.Action("Search", "Home") I have cose i was trying to have both Search and Create buttons in the same Form using the same 4 textboxes and i needed to delegate each button to an Action in the Controller (that didn't really worked out so well, but it's something i must also figure out). It is what my project is requesting.
The point of the other 3 textboxes is also for search.

Comment: That's crazy and just will not work. You need 2 separate forms, or you need to handle all this using ajax. And what is the point of all 4 textboxes. Is your query actually much more complicated and allows searching for any of the properties? In any case it would be a confusing user experience guaranteed to drive you customers away.

Comment: Well one baby step at a time. Let's just focus on this question for now. I'm not sure what u suggested me to do. Maybe u have a code sample or a link i could look at.

Comment: (1) Are you happy with using jquery/ajax? - it will give you much better performance (2) Do you initially display all the contacts in view, in which case posting to the server is unnecessary since you can display/hide rows based on your search parameters giving even better performance. (3) Can you explain how you would filter the data if say 3 of the 4 text boxes were filled in?

Comment: (1) Verry Happy! Actually i use jqGrid Autocomplete to help with Search. 

(3) I don't worry too much about multiple textboxes being filled at the same time. I just want to be able to search each row with each box. 

(2) yes i'm displaying all results initially.
ALSO those textboxes should be for editing, but that's my other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29614255/mvc-get-details-from-partial-view-to-show-in-textboxes

Comment: Need a beak for an hour, but then I'll add an answer. I've looked at you other question - its a little confusing but I think I can help with that too. Have a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9madrh7g/2/) for example of adding and editing items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your forms submit button has `onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Search", "Home")'"` which redirects to a GET method and does not pass any parameters. Your `Search()` method is marked `[HttpPost]` and expects a parameter named `searchNume`, so your `onclick()` event is not actually doing anything. Based on your comments, you can handle this using jquery (this example assumes you only want to search by the property `Nume` as indicated in the `Search()` method)

Html (replace the `<input type="submit" ..>` with)

```
<button type="button" id="search">Search by Nume</button>

<div id="results">
    @Html.Action("Search") // to initially display all contacts
</div> // place holder for the search results
```

and add the following script

```
var url = '@Url.Action("Search", "Home")';
var filter = $('#Nume');
var results = $('#results');
$('#search).click(function() {
  results.load(url, { searchNume: filter.val() });
});
```

and modify the controller method to return a partial view containing the filtered contacts

```
public PartialViewResult Search() // for displaying the initial view with all contacts
{
    List<Contact> contactsList = db.Contacts.ToList();
    return PartialView("_Contacts", contactsList);
}

[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult Search(string searchNume)
{
    // could make this IEnumerable<Contact> and avoid the extra overhead of .ToList()?
    List<Contact> contactsList; 
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchNume))
    {
        contactsList = db.Contacts.ToList();
    }
    else
    {
        contactsList = db.Contacts.Where(x => x.Nume.Contains(searchNume)).ToList();
    }
    return PartialView("_Contacts", contactsList); // partial view
}
```

and your partial view (`_Contacts.cshtml`) might look like (from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29614255/mvc-get-details-from-partial-view-to-show-in-textboxes))

```
@model IEnumerable<Demo.Models.Contact>
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ContactId)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nume)</td>
            ....
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Side note: If you initial view is displaying all contacts, then you can improve performance and avoid the call to the controller by filtering the list on the client side using javascript/jquery. There a numerous examples on the web [including this one](http://kilianvalkhof.com/2010/javascript/how-to-build-a-fast-simple-list-filter-with-jquery/)

Comment: A public action method 'Search' was not found on controller 'Demo.Controllers.HomeController'.Line 137:        @Html.Action("Search")
Maybe u know how to debug this better then me. I think the @html.Action wants another type of controller, not a PartialViewResult

Comment: I assumed the `Search()` method was in the same controller. You just need to specify the controller name, so assuming its in `ContactController` then it would be `@Html.Action("Search", "Contact")`

Comment: Everything is in the Home Controller. I get the same error even if i specify @Html.Action("Search", "Home")

Comment: Oops. Sorry, I forgot to add the GET method - will update in a moment.

Comment: Are you still there Stephen?

Comment: Always :) Are you still having problems?

Comment: I didn't noticed u already posted the GET method. I added every thing like u mentioned, and now button does nothing. I will probably have to rethink the whole thing, or admit defeat for now and get back to this project when i will have a better understanding of MVC :|

Comment: I reposted the code for Search, modified like u said but still no action from Search button. I tried with [ChildActionOnly] and without, and putting the js code in @section scrips{ }  and without, but still nothing.

Comment: Is it hitting the controller? Are you getting any error messages in the browser console? Is the value of `filter.val()` valid? Is the script at the bottom of the page or wrapped in `document.ready()`?

Comment: (1).No i'm not getting any errors. (2) I don't know how i should check that. (3) By the script at the bottom of the page i assume u refering to this script?   `$('#search').click(function () {
                results.load(url, { txtsearchNume: filter.val() });`    , and no it was just `$(function() {..}`. I tried with `$(document).ready (function() {..}` but same thing.

Comment: (2). Press F12 to open you browser tools. Check the console tab. Then spend some time looking at resources about the tools - its absolutely critical to web development that you know how to debug your scripts and understand the Network tab (what values you are receiving and sending)

Comment: Sigh. Why do people do stupid things like overriding `id` attributes. The helper generates `id="Nume"` but you then override it using `new { id = "txtSearchNume"` so `var filter = $('#Nume');` is undefined and the script fails - there is no element with `id="Nume"`, only one with `id="txtSearchNume"`

Comment: Damn! I didn't show u that before :(. I used it for jquery autocomplete and i didn't think it's important to post in question. Another thing i've learned. Bottom line is it works now! Thanks for having patience with me Stephen!

Answer (score 0):

You need a separate search model if you're going to do searching through multiple properties on the `Contact` entity.

```
// model
public class ContactSearchModel
{
    public string Nume { get; set; }
    public string Prenume { get; set; }
    public string Adresa { get; set; }
    public string Mentiuni { get; set; }
}

// view
@using Demo.Model.ContactSearchModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <th>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Nume)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Prenume)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Adresa)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Mentiuni)
    </th>
    <th>
        <input type="submit" name="submitSearch" value="Search" class="btn btn-info"
               onclick=" location.href='@Url.Action("Search", "Home")' " />
    </th>
```

And this is how you use it:

```
// controller
[HttpPost] //FOR SEARCH (WORKING)
public ActionResult Search(ContactSearchModel search)
{
    List<Contact> contactsList;
    if (search != null)
    {
        var query = db.Contacts.AsQueryable();

        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(search.Nume))
            query = query.Where(x => x.Nume.Contains(search.Nume));
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(search.Prenume))
            query = query.Where(x => x.Prenume.Contains(search.Prenume));
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(search.Adresa))
            query = query.Where(x => x.Adresa.Contains(search.Adresa));
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(search.Mentiuni))
            query = query.Where(x => x.Mentiuni.Contains(search.Mentiuni));

        contactsList = query.ToList();
    }
    else
    {
        contactsList = db.Contacts.ToList();
    }
    return View(contactsList);
}
```

Comment: I don't see how this could work. Maybe u didn't understand my question. Multumesc anyway :p

Comment: Tell me exactly what it is you want to do on the page (in romanian if necessary) and I'll help you do it.

Comment: @ Radu Porumb I have a database made out of 2 tables (Contact and ContactTelefon) and they both have ContactId field in common. I made a ADO model out of the tables and have 2 classes with same names as the tables. I need to make a table with 4 textboxes that can handle Search/Create and also Edit/Delete for each row. All must happen on the same view as far as the user is concerned. Here is a link to my other question where i posted most of the code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29614255/mvc-get-details-from-partial-view-to-show-in-textboxes . Multumesc pentru ajutor :)