# Obtain ID from table row selected

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, html

I've got some trouble by getting the correct ID from the table row selected within Datatable. The alert I'm using to see what returns from the JS script only shows the same ID from the first row selected no matter how many rows are in the table list and of course ID from each is always different(from Mysql). Confusing. Even by refreshing is still the same. Must be a little bug there within my code. Any hint?  Here it is:

PHP row output thru JSON encode:

```
$query = $mysqli->query($sql) or die;
        $data = array();
        // fetch data as array
            while($row = $query->fetch_array()) { 

                $nestedData=array(); 

                $nestedData[] = $row["email"];
                $nestedData[] = $row["ipv4"];
                $nestedData[] = $row["created"];
                // $nestedData[] = '<a class="delete" href="#"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>';
                $nestedData[] = '<button type="button" class="delbtn btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-id="'.$row['id'].'">Delete</button>';
                $nestedData[] = '<a class="btn btn-info btn-xs" href="newsModal.php?id='.$row['id'].'" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#newsModal" edit-id="'.$row['id'].'">Edit</a>';

                $data[] = $nestedData;
    }
```

Jquery:

```
$('#delbtn').click( function () {
    if ( $('tr.selected').hasClass('selected') ) {
        var id = $('td button[type=button]').attr('data-id');
        var data = {'id': id };
        alert(id);
        // $.ajax({...
```

[image: table selected delete]

```
            <div class="panel-body">
            <button type="button" id="reloadbtn" class="btn btn-default">Refresh</button>
            <button type="button" id="printbtn" class="btn btn-primary">Print</button>
            <button type="button" id="delbtn" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
        </div>

        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="table-responsive">

          <table id="tablenews" class="display compact table table-striped table-bordered table-hover ">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>E-Mail</th>
                  <th>IPv4</th>
                  <th>Created</th>
                  <th></th>
                  <th></th>
                </tr>
          </thead>
```

[image: table code]

[table trouble JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/me_h3r3/0h0uLm0b/)

Comment: `$(this).find('td button[type=button]').attr('data-id');` try this

Comment: Nope, then it says 'undefined'. I guess the reason is that <tr> selected ain't got that attribute 'data-id'. That's what I thought first would be the solution for the problem.

Comment: can you add the rendered html

Comment: Alright, I edited my post by adding an image for tbody. The data for that is rendered by JSON in PHP. Watch the last pic attached.

Comment: You can give id to tr itself. Something like this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142422/get-id-of-selected-row-in-a-table-html

Comment: Or try this - var id = $tr.find('td:nth-child(3) button[type=button]').attr('data-id');

Comment: The last one doesn't seem to be working for me. Nothing returns. Kinda odd. Normally I'd have to go downwards from <tr>to the td with ID and attribute. Yes, of course giving <tr> an ID would be an option but that's not what I wanted. How else can I fetch this <td> with ID?

Comment: As I said, var id = $('.delbtn').attr('data-id'); returns the ID but then it's static. No matter if I select another table row ID remains the same.

Comment: I  just spotted this mistake... I think it is the culprit. You are using $('#delbtn').click( function () { - which is wrong. Because button ids have to be unique. And that is why it is fetching the same id. It could be $('.delbtn').click( function () { - or  $("tbody tr").click(function () {.  Try it.

Comment: @T.Shah, nope, I've tried either a class or ID for the button outside the table but it doesn't make any difference. Btw, by adding a button to the certain table row itself the correct ID is fetched and works just fine. $("#tablenews tbody").on('click', '.delbtn', function(){
    
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    var data = 'id=' + id ; 
    alert(id);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this helps:

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable();

    $('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
        if ( $(this).hasClass('selected') ) {
            $(this).removeClass('selected');
        }
        else {
            table.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');
        }
    } );

    $('#button').click( function () {
        if ( $('tr.selected').hasClass('selected') ) {

      var id = $('tr.selected button.delbtn').attr('data-id');
      var data = 'id=' + id ;
      alert(id);

      // $.ajax({
                         // type: "POST",
                         // url: "newsdelrow.php",
                         // data: data,
                         // cache: false,
                         // success: function(response) { 


                         // alert(response);

                        // }
                    // });

        // table.row('.selected').remove().draw( false );

     }else { alert('Please select a table row first'); }

    } );

    $("#example tbody").on('click', '.delbtn', function(){

                var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
                var data = 'id=' + id ; //  var data = {'name': name } can be used instead

                 alert(id);

    });
} );
```

Comment: I made a JSFiddle for this issue so you can see what I'm talking about. There the same trouble with the ID and Delete Button on top occurs. Help is still needed for this. https://jsfiddle.net/me_h3r3/0h0uLm0b/

Comment: just add this: var id = $('tr.selected button.delbtn').attr('data-id');

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:

```
     $('#button').click( function () {
        if ( $('tr.selected').hasClass('selected') ) {
          alert($('tr.selected button.delbtn').attr('data-id'));
        }
        else { 
          alert('Please select a table row first'); 
        }
     });
```

Comment: Nah, alert says: 'undefined'. No ID is being fetched.

Comment: i have modified your jsfiddle code now its working - [jsfiddle.net/0h0uLm0b/4/](https://jsfiddle.net/0h0uLm0b/4/)

Comment: OMG, great! Now it works as expected. From now on I'm going to use that JSFiddle for my tiny bugs within the code. Sometimes it's way too simple but the blind need help to see :-D. Look at all this here for the missing tr.selected line. Alright, you guys, amazing, much obliged!